# Callback with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I have a function x1 that has a ajax call to the server something like below

```
var result;

function x1()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url, // Location of the service        
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server        
        success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
            result = msg.GetUrlContentResult; 
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I have another function x11 that calls x1 that depends on this value of variable result which is global var.

```
function x11()
{
    x1();
    if (result==something)
    {do something}
}
```

**problem is since x1() is async function the result is not set when the if result get's executed. i think i have to do some type of callback,** looking at some examples for callback i am little new to this any help how to correctly setup a callback so value of result is set when it returns from x1? i have more than one function that calls x1()

Comment: What if you put the "if (result==something) {do something}" part within the success callback function? You could also add it to the error callback function if essential.

Comment: i have more than one function that calls x1() and process the result diffrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is actually something as simple as this: (edited for dynamic callback)

```
function x1(callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url, // Location of the service        
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server        
        success: callback,
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        }
    });
}

x1(x11);
```

You'll have to modify the x11 function to accept the `msg` argument and update the `result` variable:

```
function x11(msg) {
    result = msg.GetUrlContentResult;
    //...
}
```

Comment: but i have function x1 that can be called by multiple functions not just x11

Comment: Ok, will update answer

Comment: can you also implement sucess: on x1 and then at the bottom of the sucess do callback?
sucess:{//do something 
callback}

Comment: Sure. You could create an anonymous function and do stuff there first. But when you invoke the callback make sure you use parentheses: `callback()`.

Comment: when you say modify x11 to accept result what do you mean?

Comment: Updated to demonstrate

Answer (score 3):

A single ajax call can have multiple success handlers.  Return the [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) from `x1()` and bind an additional `success` handler to it from `x11()` using the [`.done()` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/):

```
function x1()
{
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}
function x11()
{
    x1().done(function(msg) {
        // this is an additional success handler
        // both handlers will be called
    });
}
```

Comment: do i need to add the return next to $.ajax?

Comment: @JustinHomes - Yes.  Otherwise the `x1()` returns `undefined` and you'll get a runtime error when you try to call `x1().success()`.  There is no method "success" of undefined.

Comment: @JustinHomes - If your real function doesn't actually exit immediately after making the ajax call, you can store the `jqXHR` object in a variable and return the variable at the end of the function.

Comment: The `.success()` method is deprecated in favor of `.done()`